# How can i get customer data from observer after successful login?

Tags: event-observer, customer, login

I have made a custom module in which I have an observer file. I need to display all information about the logged in user.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the event `customer_login`:

```
<customer_login>
    <observers>
        <yourobservername>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>yourmodule/path_to_class</class>
            <method>customerLogin</method>
        </yourobservername>
    </observers>
</customer_login>
```

Your observer class would look like this:

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    }
}
```

Comment: after i do this the getCustomer returns null.

Comment: See the revision. Cheers.

Comment: Heyy.. I am very new in magento.I also want to do same thing.Can you tell me where i have to put this code in file structure?

Comment: I want before login action when user login wrong password login.

Comment: @ravipatel ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
    if($customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
$customer =  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
       $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId())->getData();
       //for firstname
       $customerFirstName = $customerData['firstname'];
    }
```

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()` is enough to get customer details, then why reload customer instance again ?

Comment: Yes it is not required .
But I edited according to the code flow 
$customer -> getFirstname() will also work .