# Adding custom attribute to Customer

Tags: module, attributes, magento-1, customer

We need a simple way to add an attribute to a customer record that is not editable by the customer or admin, only programatically. Essentially, we have an ExpressionEngine site coupled with Magento.

We authenticate via webservice and would like to store some JSON that we get back from the authentication into the customer's record and update it each time they login.

We will also want the data modified if they change information in the checkout process, such as shipping address. We will then send the data back to our webservice as we currently do that with each order.

Is this difficult to do as we are now storing some JSON on each product using a custom attribute with MageWorx's Custom Options extension?

I used the Online Module Creator here http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ but am not sure how to modify or retrieve the value once the module is installed.

Where could I learn how to write an extension to do this?

Comment: X-Ref: [Adding attributes to customer entity](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5961290/367456) (May 2011)

Comment: How to do if I want to save this attribute value into 'customer_entity' database table? @Marius

Comment: @KazimNoorani If you want to save the value directly in the `customer_entity` table you need to add the column to the table and in the script that adds the attribute (see my answer below) replace the type from `varchar` to `static`.

Comment: @Marius I already added column in `customer_entity` table. And my attribute is of type 'select'. I want to save my attribute value directly at this 'custom_column' in `customer_entity` table. How to do that?

Comment: Even if you want to save the data in the main table you still need an attribute with the type static.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**/app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/sql/your_customattribute_setup/install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$setup->addAttribute("customer", "customattribute",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Custom Attribute",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "Custom Attribute"
));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "customattribute");

$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'customattribute',
    '999'  //sort_order
);

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
//$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
//$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100)
                ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

**/app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/etc/config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Your_Customattribute>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Your_Customattribute>
        </modules>
        <global>

            <resources>
                <Your_Customattribute_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Your_Customattribute</module>
                        <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_setup>
                <Your_Customattribute_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_write>
                <Your_Customattribute_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_read>
            </resources>
        </global>

    </config>
```

**app/etc/modules/Your_Customattribute.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Your_Customattribute>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Your_Customattribute>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

Then to retrieve or edit you use:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($custid);
$customer->getCustomattribute();
$customer->setCustomattribute($yourjson);
```

You will have to create event observers for the login event, answered here: [How can i get customer data from observer after successful login?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6427/how-can-i-get-customer-data-from-observer-after-successful-login)

and also likely observers for the customer_save_after in case they alter their address in account mgmt, and one for the quote, which could be in different places depending on what you are going for.

Comment: What is customer_band_sku?

Comment: Sorry, that was one I created leftover.

Comment: So how would setCustomAttribute() work to set the data?

Comment: Do you have an example of how to SET the data when the user logs in?

Comment: Yes, I mention it above. Use Phil Winkles answer in the link to observe a customer logging in. In that observer you would use the above snippet: $customer->setCustomattribute($yourjson);

Comment: By having `<class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>` under `global > resources > setup` you make your module some what specific to setting up `customer` attributes. It may be better to not provide the `<class>` tag here, and instead change `$installer = $this;` to `$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');` and ditch the `$setup` var.

Comment: Hi, i got this error message "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute() " i am using Magento 1.9.0.x

Comment: Working good..could you also tell how to show that attribute in admin panel+ customer grid

Comment: Does not work with magento 1.9. I followed all steps but I can't set or read the data.

Answer (score 9):

There is a lot of custom functionality you'll have to create yourself as [custom module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table) overriding classes, and hooking into events where you want data passed to your web service. As far as the attribute goes, when you create your custom module and define a setup resource for it in the module's `config.xml` like in the tutorial above, then in your install script you can do something like this:

**[module_path]/sql/[resource_node_defined_in_config_xml]/mysql4-install-[module_version_number].php**

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup ();

$setup = Mage::getModel ( 'customer/entity_setup' , 'core_setup' );

    //add budget
    $setup->addAttribute('customer', 'budget', array(
        'type' => 'decimal',
        'input' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Budget',
        'global' => 1,
        'visible' => 1,
        'required' => 0,
        'user_defined' => 0,
        'default' => '',
        'visible_on_front' => 1,
        'source' =>   NULL,
        'comment' => 'This is a budget'
    ));

$installer->endSetup ();
```

`user_defined` makes the attribute a `system` attribute if set to `0`, which disables the ability to delete it from the admin.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of core debugging I found out that magento expects the file to be in either **data/Companyname_Modulname_setup/** or in **sql/Companyname_Modulname_setup/**.

And it has to be named `mysql4-data-upgrade-OLDVERSION-NEWVERSION.php` e.g. `mysql4-data-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.0.php` instead of `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`

At least on Magento 1.9.3