# How to add a custom field in Customer module in Magento 1.8.1?

Tags: magento-1.8, customer-attribute

I would like to add a Custom Field in Customer Registration, Edit and same should allow from Admin also?

Also it should be able to add via SOAP method.

I am using magento CE 1.8.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to create a customer Attribute

Comment: why is this a duplicate? that other question is quite different, he wants things programatically and not editable by the customer. quite different

Answer (score 3):

The Easy Way to create Customer Attribute is below

Use this to create a module that does that:

http://silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Then go to the 'Need add Customer Attribute section'. It's pretty self-explanatory.

Play with it!

it's a **VERY** useful tool. You can see that there is more to it than making a module that provides new customer attributes. Also read up on clearing caches / compilation before installing new modules.

If you want do via script then Follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer)

Comment: Thanks Kayul for your response. But here I am looking for to add an attribute in existing module rather creating my own module.

Comment: Ok no problem then you can create the via code