# Base currency is CAD, but need to see USD prices in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

My base prices are in CAD (Canadian Dollars), I am trying to create an attribute which will show converted USD prices in the Backend. It must be an attribute, because I will need that converted USD price attribute to create Google Feeds.

So far, converted USD prices are only visible on the Fronend.

Please help guys! I would very much appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you want to see usd all price in price field at frontend

Comment: @AmitBera Front end Shows Base price in CAD, and if a customer wants to see USD price, they click conversion link.

I want to see, or at least have an attribute in the backend for USD converted prices.  Because generally, I do not see what the price for my products in the USD, until I go to the front-page and click convert USD prices.

Comment: can you just convert the price during creating Google Feed?

Comment: @alex_b Its best to have an attribute set which will show/contain converted USD prices. Manually punching in USD prices in the feed is hard in my cases, and sometimes they may change. Let say I change base price CAD for a product and don't  make manual change in the USD pricing in the data feed, google will show my previous manually inputted USD price.

Comment: But if you convert attribute `price` during creating the feed it always will be correctly set in all currencies. In order to just see how it will be converted into another price you can use that select in product grid http://i.imgur.com/9u4bg8R.png or you can change the store in Store Switcher on product edit page in the admin

Comment: @alex_b Interesting, but the thing is, I need to export a feed which will include: CAD price (which is fine), and USD price(it's converted). I don't know how to create USD_converted_price attribute.

Comment: any help guys ??

Comment: I understand what you need. And I'm telling about modifying feed export. You just need to rewrite appropriate class which is responsible for export and there include USD price wich will be converted right there during the export, just get base price and convert it like that `Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($amount, $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode);` and include the value to the feed. In such case you do not need to worry about one more attribute for the price

Comment: @alex_b The problem is  I use a 3rd party feed exporter.. and I must inlude on their platform the attribute for USD prices. What you have mentioned seems like its going to do the job, but not in my cases. I really appreciate the help !!

Comment: Got it. In that case you can implement it in the following way:
create new attribute like `price_usd`, specify `backend_model` for it. In the backend model class you can extract base price from a product, convert it to desired currency and save the value. Also you can display that attribute on product edit page. In that case you can set it as read only since it will be saved automatically

Comment: @alex_b Thank you for providing some light to the problem. If I can ask, could you please provide me instructions how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

That is solution with new attribute and backend_model that I mentioned in comments above:

Create new attribute first:

```
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'price_usd', array(
    'type'                       => 'decimal',
    'label'                      => 'USD Price',
    'input'                      => 'text',
    'backend'                    => 'yourmodule/product_attribute_backend_usdprice',
    'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
    'required'                   => false,
    'searchable'                 => false,
    'filterable'                 => false,
    'comparable'                 => false,
    'is_configurable'            => false,
   'group'                      => 'Price'
));
```

Then create class which represents model `yourmodule/product_attribute_backend_usdprice`;

The content is like this:

```
class Your_Module_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Usdprice extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Before save method
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $object
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attrCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $basePrice = $object->getData('price');

        $value = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($basePrice, Mage::app()->getStore()->getDefaultCurrencyCode(), 'USD');
        $object->setData($attrCode, $value);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Make sure that `Mage::app()->getStore()->getDefaultCurrencyCode()` returns `CAD` value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please tell where can I find these files to edit. ( I am not too mage savvy yet.)

Comment: Its new files. You should create your own module and put them to it

Comment: Yes, but where to place the module once I create it ? app/design? where

Comment: There are tons of articles about it over the internet. Look at http://insync.co.in/creating-custom-module-magento/

Comment: I have created an module, based on the instruction you have provided and also this example
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer

I dont see "price_usd" attribute in the magento admin under Manage Attributes

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. After million of trial and errors, I have managed to isntall the code attribute. Its visible in core_resource and eav_attribute.

I went ahead and tried extracting the products I get this error Invalid backend model specified: my_extension/model_product_attribute_backend_usdprice

Comment: I also tried this: my_extension/product_attribute_backend_usdprice
but same error as post above.

Comment: Have you created the model itself?

Comment: Yes I did. It got installed.. I see price_USD attribute in magento attribute panel.
I created another topic so maybe others can see where I went wrong.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41885/error-invalid-backend-model-specified-when-extracting-product-data/41892#41892

Comment: Error that you have can be easily solved. Follow the answer in another topic. Will appreciate your feedback about the answer in current topic

Comment: I would really like to Thank You for helping me out, I managed to install the module, everything works.
Could you pleas clarify two things:
1. In Catalog--> Manage Products, USD price are rounded to two digits:  152.68... But when I export the prices they are not rounded, are shown as 152.6816. How can I receive already rounded prices ?

Comment: Second question, for me to export the USD prices, I have to go to each product and save it, and I have do for every product in the catalog. Otherwise fields in EXCEL for Price_USD column will be Empty. I cleaned and refreshed Cache, and did reindex management.. but nothign helps. I have to manually go to each product and save it. Only after i save it, USD prices are shown in the price field inside the product itself and in the excel. What could I do.
Once again, THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!

Comment: 1) how do you export the prices?
2) Think you need to implement an observer for reindex process and in it get product default price and convert it to USD

Comment: 1. To export I go to System-> Import/Export--> Data Flow-Profiles (and click on Export All products). In the column price_usd are 4 digits past period (12.5747) and not rounded by 2 digits.(12.58)

Comment: 2. Alex, could you please provide the code for the observer, I will try to implement it. ( I don't know how to write php code yet, just learned how to implement module).

Comment: Anyone can help ?