# ERROR: Invalid backend model specified: (when extracting product data)

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am trying to setup a module that will extract my Base (CAD) Canadian prices and show converted USD price. To me it seems like I set up everything as needed, but there is error in the admin panel when I try to EXTRACT product data.

> ERROR:  Invalid backend model specified:
>   customcatattrb/product_attribute_backend
>
> /htdocs/app/code/local/Meteorify/Customcatattrb/sql/customcatattrb_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'price_usd', array(
    'type'                       => 'decimal',
    'label'                      => 'USD Price',
    'input'                      => 'text',
    'backend'                    => 'customcatattrb/product_attribute_backend_usdprice',
    'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
    'required'                   => false,
    'searchable'                 => false,
    'filterable'                 => false,
    'comparable'                 => false,
    'is_configurable'            => false,
   'group'                      => 'Price'
));
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

> htdocs/app/code/local/Meteorify/Customcatattrb/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Usdprice.php

```
class Meteorify_Customcatattrb_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Usdprice extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Before save method
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $object
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attrCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $basePrice = $object->getData('price');

        $value = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($basePrice, Mage::app()->getStore()->getDefaultCurrencyCode(), 'USD');
        $object->setData($attrCode, $value);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Could someone please check the codes above and see if there are any problems causing the error**

**Invalid backend model specified: customcatattrb/product_attribute_backend**

Comment: Did you define the `<models>` node correctly in the `config.xml`? Paste it here, if you can.

Comment: @laketuna I believe so, Yes. The module is installed. I see attributes in Magento admin, Its just there is an error when I export products. This is how I configured config.xml
<module>Meteorify_Customcatattrb</module>
<class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>

Comment: @laketuna
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Meteorify_Customcatattrb>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Meteorify_Customcatattrb>
  </modules>
    <global>
      <resources>
          <customcatattrb_setup>
            <setup>
              <module>Meteorify_Customcatattrb</module>
              <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
              <use>default_setup</use>
            </connection>
          </customcatattrb_setup>
     </resources>
   </global>
</config>

Answer (score 1):

Your installation script configuration is correct if your script is run and you get that error. I don't see in your pasted `config.xml` the following..

```
<config>
    ....
    <global>
        <models>
            <customcatattrb>
                <class>Meteorify_Customcatattrb_Model</class>
            </customcatattrb>
            ...
        </models>
        ...
    </global>
</config>
```

Did you define the above, which tells Magento where your models are? When you use `customcatattrb/product_attribute_backend_usdprice`, Magento looks for your `<model>`'s definition of where your model classes are supposed to be. Give it a shot.

Comment: I actually don't have this particular code in my config. But the module got isntalled without it. Where in code should I insert it?

Comment: It must be in the `config.xml`. Let me format it for you better..

Comment: Thank you for helping me with index.php. I would like to ask you, how to create an Observer for Reindex for this function ?