# Adding a Custom Column to Customers Grid

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-attribute, customer-grid

am tring to show a Custom Customer attribute in Customer Grid by using this code
http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-column-to-customers-grid-alternative-way/

its showing the values if am using default magento columns as index
but how can i use a custom text field attribute ?

```
        if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/customer_grid') {
/* @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid */
        $block->addColumnAfter('origin', array(
            'header'    => 'origin',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
        ), 'group');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to create the custom Customer attribute you want to use. You may use the install script to create this attribute.
See this answer: [Adding custom attribute to Customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer)

Then use attribute's code as index.

Comment: i have already installed an extension to create customer attribute,and created a custom attribute using that.

Comment: Are u sure attribute is added ? Also what error are you getting when give the new attribute code as index ?

Comment: No Errors, the values are not displaying but i think they automatically adding some prefix in the index value.