# How to add a telephone number directly to the customer and not a billing address

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-account, customer-session

Essentially, I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$customer = $session->getCustomer();
$customer->setTelephone($telephone);
$customer->save();
```

And such as this:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$customer = $session->getCustomer();        
$response["telephone"] = $customer->getTelephone();
```

Without having to add a default billing/shipping address, since the customer will need to enter his mobile number on registration, but not a billing/shipping address.

Is that possible?

Comment: visit the link:-http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/

Comment: I don't want to use the address though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no exit which function which will do it.

- Need to add `an customer attribute to Customer  entity type` which will save the telephone to customer table.
  Which will show on `customer registration,edit,checkout form`.

See how to
   install an Customer attribute in magento
   [Adding custom attribute to Customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer)

There it should no relation between billing/shipping telephone.

Also. need more detail checkout at http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/