# how to get only street address as they sign up

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

Is there any way to add the address form to the registration form or any free addon to add an extra field to the registration form so that I can get the customer location as they sign up?

I tried many times with  `<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true);?>` this code but i want only street address it gives `company name , country` etc. ui want just street address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,it not `really good idea to Only show`  street-address on `register form by disabling by rest of address field.`

[@saravanavelu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/75771/4564) solve your visualization on register  form but you must get error whenever  want  to save that address. `Because of customer/adderss does save rest of required fields like city,zipcode,country value`.Then Magento customer address Model (customer/address) `Thrown  error`.

Better idea to add a new  `a customer attribute to Customer  entity type` which will `save the street address to customer table`. Which will show on `customer registration,edit,checkout form address`.

**See how to**
   install an Customer attribute in magento
   [Adding custom attribute to Customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer)

Also. need more detail checkout at http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/

Answer (score 0):

try this code:-
Fields on sign up

By default Magento does not show the address fields within “Create an Account”. To make the sign up process more user friendly you can enable the address fields by adding the following:

**Open app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form\register.phtml**

Before

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

Add

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true); ?>
```

try this extension:-http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/registration-address.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works,

In `local.xml,`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0"> 
    <customer_account_create>
        <reference name="customer_form_register">       
            <action method="setShowAddressFields"><param>true</param></action>
            <action method="setShowStreetAddressFields"><param>1</param></action>
            <action method="setShowOtherFields"><param>0</param></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>
</layout>
```

In `register.phtml,`

Find `<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>`

Replace the below code,

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
        <div class="fieldset">
            <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Address Information') ?></h2>
            <ul class="form-list">
            <?php if($this->getShowStreetAddressFields()): ?>
                <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
                    <li class="wide">
                        <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                    <li class="wide">
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?php echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($this->getShowOtherFields()): ?>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue', "<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>");
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="zip" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1" />
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: require  field validation "City" is a required value.
        "City" length must be equal or greater than 1 characters.
        "Country" is a required value.
        "Zip" is a required value.
        "Telephone" is a required value.
        "Telephone" length must be equal or greater than 1 characters.
        Please enter the city.
        Please enter the telephone number.
        Please enter the zip/postal code.
        Please enter the country.

Comment: by default country,City,Telephone,Zip is required field.   you can remove required value for these attributes by update attributes by sql script. But It will affect in all the forms

Comment: yes but its possible to only allow street address field. i don't want to need telephone,city etc...