# My Custom Attribute not Getting in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, customer-address

I have created a custom attribute in Customer Address (`govt_id`) and it is showing on Adminhtml UI, but when I retrieve the customer address attributes it's not getting it.

**my setup code:**

```
<?php

$this->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');


$setup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'govt_id', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'GOVT ID',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => '0',
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
));

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'govt_id')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))->save();

$this->endSetup();
```

And i'm getting attributes by using below code

```
$magentoAttributes = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getAttributes();
        foreach(array_keys($magentoAttributes) as $att)
        {
            $name = $att;
            $this->magentoOptions[$att] = $name;

        }
        Mage::log( $this->magentoOptions);
```

Result:

```
2015-09-14T06:35:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [entity_id] => entity_id
    [entity_type_id] => entity_type_id
    [increment_id] => increment_id
    [parent_id] => parent_id
    [attribute_set_id] => attribute_set_id
    [created_at] => created_at
    [updated_at] => updated_at
    [prefix] => prefix
    [firstname] => firstname
    [middlename] => middlename
    [lastname] => lastname
    [suffix] => suffix
    [company] => company
    [street] => street
    [city] => city
    [country_id] => country_id
    [region] => region
    [region_id] => region_id
    [postcode] => postcode
    [telephone] => telephone
    [fax] => fax
    [vat_is_valid] => vat_is_valid
    [vat_request_id] => vat_request_id
    [vat_request_date] => vat_request_date
    [vat_request_success] => vat_request_success
    [vat_id] => vat_id
)
```

Here the `govt_id` attribute is missing.

I have cleared cache also, but still it's not getting Why?

Did I do anything wrong or is something missing?

Comment: I have updated my answer plz check it .

Answer (score 1):

Set `visible_on_front` to 1

Change it from:

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'govt_id', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'GOVT ID',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => '0',
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
));
```

To :

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'govt_id', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'GOVT ID',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => '',
    'source' =>   NULL,
    'visible_on_front' => 1
));
```

For More detail see here:
[Adding custom attribute to Customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer)

Answer (score 0):

To verify this,

Check tables

1. `eav_attribute` if there is a row with `attribute_code = govt_id` and `entity_type_id` as 1
2. If 1 is no, then attribute has not been created, if yes check now in table `customer_eav_attribute` if the `attribute_id` exists
3. If 2 is yes, you have successfully created a customer entity attribute
4. Check in table customer `customer_form_attribute` (this is to check if for the forms you have added an entry has been added to this table)

Check if 3 if the above points are verified, you should have successfully created a customer entity attribute