# Free shipping / delivery set per customer

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, free-shipping

Is it possible or is there an extension that will allow me to set free delivery for customers at customer level and not customer group level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved. You can approach this following way,

1. Create a customer attribute to set whether the customer is allowed to get free delivery. To create a customer attribute you can follow these links

a. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961290/adding-attributes-to-customer-entity

b. [Adding custom attribute to Customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer)

2. Once the customer attribute is created you can assign your customers to allow free delivery.
3. Now in your shipping module's collectRates() function you can check whether the customer is allowed free delivery, if it returns true you can set this

> $shippingPrice = '0.00';

Thanks.