# Country,Zip code and state fields not showing on frontend

Tags: customer, register

Dropdown for Country and State is not display on the frontend customer register form.
I am trying to find a configuration from admin as it is available by default.

Comment: I found the answer, You can show the address fields by adding the following to local.xml                                                    <customer_account_create>
        <reference name="customer_form_register">
              <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value>       </action>
        </reference>
</customer_account_create>

Comment: Add answer following in answer box. and accept - upvote it. If will be helpful to other users

Comment: Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can search in this site or google [how to add customer attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer). The specific for you case is that your attribute should be with:

```
'type'   => 'varchar',
'input'  => 'select',
'source' => 'customer/entity_address_attribute_source_country',
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This method will enable all address fields but what if i want to enable only country field?
I can edit in Register.phtml and comment other fields or I will write the country <div> out of if condition but any other way if you know?