# How to add new customer attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-attribute, entities

I want to add a new attribute for the customers: continent.

First of all, I have created a new module for this where I'm inserting this new attribute:

```
<?php

$this->addAttribute('customer', 'continent', array(
    'type'      => 'int',
    'label'     => 'Continent',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'position'  => 120,
    'required'  => true,
    'is_system' => 0,
));

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'continent');
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();
?>
```

There's nothing to show in the frontend, everything in the backend depending on the chosen country.

And now I want to implement the logic when a new user register or edits his personal info. Something like:

if country = US then continent = 1, 
if country = UK then continent = 2, 
and so on...

I want to kepp a static file (XML?) somewhere with the relationships between countries and continents.

```
<US>1</US>
<UK>2</UK>
```

Comment: See here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer

Answer (score 0):

Answered here:
[Admin customer set option_id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110314/admin-customer-set-option-id/121564#121564)

In your source model you can read an XML file if you want ... or you just add the continents there.

If you use `varchar` as type instead of int you can even write north america, south america, europe, africa, ... into the db so it is still readable.