# Admin customer set option_id

Tags: admin, customer

I'm trying to add a custom drop down to my customer in the admin area of Magento. I want to be able to control the option_id for each option in the drop down instead of it just incrementing, how do I go about doing this?

Here is what I've got:

```
function AddCustomerField($setup, $data)
{
    $entityTypeId = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
    $attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

    $attr = array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'input' => 'select',
        'label' => 'Test',
        'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
        'required' => '0',
        'user_defined' => '1',
        'unique' => '0',
        'global' => '1',
        'visible' => '1',
        'searchable' => '1',
        'filterable' => '1',
        'comparable' => '1',
        'position' => '1',
        'option' =>
            array(
                'values' =>
                    array(
                        999 => 'Green22', // I want the drop down value to be 999 but it just auto increments instead
                    ),
            ),
    );
    $setup->addAttribute('customer', $data['id'], $attr);

    $setup->addAttributeToGroup($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, $data['id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want control over the values of the dropdown you need to use a source model.

[As always, inchoo wrote about this.](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-custom-attribute-source-type/)

To have your own source model extend `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract` and implement `$_option`