# Add Attribute to All Magento Customers, preferably an Object

Tags: module, magento-1, customer, custom, customer-attribute

Before continuing I would like to state that I have been looking for over a week through StackOverFlow, StackExchange, Google, and Alan Storm blogs.

Please don't link to another post I've most likely read it, instead just view my code and compare it to whatever you want to link and tell me why their way works and mine doesn't.

QUESTION: I want to add an attribute to all customers either an Object that has 3 Keys and 3 Values OR 3 separate values.
Here is my Setup so far.

> app/code/local/Sean/CustomerAddCustomAttr/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_CustomerAddCustomAttr>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Sean_CustomerAddCustomAttr>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <CustomerAddCustomAttr_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Sean_CustomerAddCustomAttr</module>
                    <class>Sean_CustomerAddCustomAttr_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </CustomerAddCustomAttr_setup>
            <CustomerAddCustomAttr_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </CustomerAddCustomAttr_write>
            <CustomerAddCustomAttr_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </CustomerAddCustomAttr_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Sean/CustomerAddCustomAttr/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Setup.php

```
<?php
class Sean_CustomerAddCustomAttr_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup {

}
```

> app/code/local/Sean/CustomerAddCustomAttr/sql/CustomerAddCustomAttr_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'silver', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'int',
    'label' => 'Silver Membership',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'default' => "",
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
    'source' => NULL,
));

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'gold', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'int',
    'label' => 'Gold Membership',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'default' => "",
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
    'source' => NULL,
));

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'platinum', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'int',
    'label' => 'Platinum Membership',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'default' => "",
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
    'source' => NULL,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

I've tested and it gets to my installation page because I tried die("We made it to the installation!) at the top and that showed.

However when I run

> $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer');
>   var_dump($customer);
>   The current customer and all other customers don't have the Silver Gold and Platinum attributes :/

I can see that the customer doesn't have any new attributes :(
Can anyone explain why? Or see an error in my code? I've tried deleting the CustomerAddCustomAttr_setup table and refreshing/clearing the Magento Cache but no cigar :/

I have read the following:
http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm
http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732761/magento-create-new-customer-attribute
[Adding custom attribute to Customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer)
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/
http://www.magecorner.com/adding-custom-customer-attributes/

Comment: Can you elaborate, what you mean with "add an object/associative array as an attribute"? Your code adds the attribute as a text field. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: For now I would be content settling with just adding a single text field. However even that is not working... In the very end though I would love to have an object.

Comment: Once I activate my module will it automatically run the install scripts?

Comment: if you named it  `install-0.0.1.php`, and did not add it **after** you added the `<customerattribute_setup>` node to your config.xml, yes.

Comment: Then remove the "customerattribute_setup" row from the "core_resource" database table and clean the cache to trigger the script again

Comment: I know this may call for a separate question but how can I see the "core_resource" database table to check if its there first? Also thank you for taking the time to help out! I'll be sure to upvote you once this works :)

Comment: Using your favorite database editor, command line or phpMyAdmin `select * from core_resource` or `select * from core_resource where code = 'customerattribute_setup'`

Comment: Okay so i deleted the row then added a die to my install script at the top and  Magento got to it however it still didn't add the attribute :( AT LEAST i know it's getting to the install script

Comment: I'm going to edit the question so it's more clear and I'll make the examples less complicated. Also Fsch & R.S can u guys leave questions after so I can upvote? I want to give u guys points for helping me out! :D

Answer (score 1):

### From the comments:

If you named the script `install-0.0.1.php`, and did not add it after you added the `<customerattribute_setup>` node to your config.xml, it should have been executed.

Otherwise, fix that, then remove the "customerattribute_setup" row from the "core_resource" database table and clean the cache to trigger the script again.

---

### After your update:

> ```
> $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer'); var_dump($customer);
> ```
>
> The current customer and all other customers
>   don't have the Silver Gold and Platinum attributes :/

I think your testing method is flawed. To see an EAV attribute in the object, it first has to have a non-null value. But as long you don't **save** the customer, no values for the attribute exist (in `customer_entity_int`).

#### How to check if an attribute has been created:

1. look it up in the `eav_attributes` table:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'gold';
   ```

   ***-OR-***
2. Test if saving the attribute works, given an existing customer with ID `$customerId`:

   - **save**

     ```
     $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
     $customer->setData('silver', 1);
     $customer->setData('gold', 1);
     $customer->setData('platin', 1);
     $customer->save();
     ```
   - **load**

     ```
     $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
     var_dump(
         $customer->getData('silver'),
         $customer->getData('gold'),
         $customer->getData('platin')
     );
     ```

Comment: Thank You. I've literally been spending all week trying to get this to work and you helped in so many ways :).  Quick question though, instead of having to set the values to something other than NULL is there a way I could just preset them all to "0" in the install script?

Comment: Well, there is a "default" field for attributes, but it does not work with EAV models like the customer, at least it does not create values for existing customers. I would do this with an SQL query like `insert into customer_entity_int (entity_id,attribute_id,value) select entity_id, 666, 0 from customer_entity`. Replace 666 with the id of the attribute that you found in `eav_attributes`. You can execute the query in your install script with `$this->run($query)`. **Warning:** I wrote that one from the top of my head, test it first!

Comment: haha okay well I wanted to stay away from mySQL queries I know the other ways of updating them so no worries :)! What would happen hypothetically if I deleted my Sean Directory and everything in it along with the Sean_CustomerAddCustomAttr.xml module? Would the customers still retain their new attributes?