# Add extra field like "Company name" in Registration Form

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i add an extra field like "Company Name" at the time of Registration and then save that data in database.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332434/adding-additional-field-to-registration-form-in-magento-1-9

Comment: please refer this one -> http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer