# How to save attribute field from new customer form backend to database table?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, customer, backend, customer-attribute

I have created new attribute and got select field i.e. dropdown in `add new customer` form in backend. I want to save that field value into database table '`customer_entity`'. How to save that field value into database?

Comment: You are looking for magento 1.X?

Comment: @Ramsystematix Yes. Magento 1.9x

Comment: You will find solution here, below link will help you, How to add custom customer attribute and set this in to database.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer

Comment: $setup = Mage::getModel ( 'customer/entity_setup' , 'core_setup' );
  customer_entity and core table are the two tables. Right? @Ramsystematix

Comment: Let me explain you...

Comment: Ya please.. @Ramsystematix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49768/discussion-between-kazim-noorani-and-ram-systematix).