# Last step of how to add a customer attribute

Tags: customer-attribute

I am a newbie, could you please explain the last step of this tutorial? How can I retrieve it?
[Adding custom attribute to Customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer)

Then to retrieve or edit you use:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($custid);
$customer->getCustomattribute();
$customer->setCustomattribute($yourjson);
```

Answer (score 0):

this talks about setting and retrieving the value for the customer attribute you just added.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($custid);
```

retrieves the customer instance from the db.
And on this object you can call

```
 $customer->getCustomattribute();
```

and you will get the value of the custom attribute you just added.

To set a value for the custom attribute just call

```
$customer->setCustomattribute($yourjson);
```

If you want your new value to be persisted in the db you need to call `$customer->save()` after setting the value for your attribute.