# Login with one of the two passwords - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, security, password

I have created a customer attribute `custom_password` witch I would check if the user didn't insert the natif password, I check in the second one `getCustomPassword()` if it's correct i log it, What is the best way to do it.

```
public function loginPostAction(){
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        $session = $this->_getSession();

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');

            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {

                if (strpos($login['username'], '@') === false){
                    Mage::log('Customer has entered a phone number ');

                    //pin code authentification
                    $customer2 = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('phone_number', $login['username'])
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_password', $login['password'])
                        ->getFirstItem();
                    Mage::log($customer2); // here i get the right customer

                    // Here we will log a customer
                    try{
                        if($customer2->getEntityId()){
                            $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer2);
                            Mage::log('Customer logged');
                        }else{
                            throw new Exception($this->__('Customer not found'));
                        }
                    }catch (Exception $e){
                        $session->addError($e->getMessage());
                    }
                    $this->_redirect('customer/account');
                //end pin code authentification
                }

                try {
                    $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                        $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                    }
                } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $value = $this->_getHelper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                            $message = $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    $session->addError($message);
                    $session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
                }
            } else {
                $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
            }
        }

        $this->_loginPostRedirect();
    }
```

Comment: Please explain how you created this `custom_password` attribute so that we better understand how it works and give proper advise. I hope it's not a simple text attribute, this would be a security nightmare!

Comment: I created two attributes : `phone_number` and `custom_password` so when a user enter a phone number he should enter a custom password else when he enter an email adress he enter a natif magento password, and befor saving the `custom_password` i encrypte it in md5, these attributes i created them like this tuto http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14165/48355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get customer, try below code to login.

```
public function loginPostAction(){
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');

        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {

            if (strpos($login['username'], '@') === false){
                Mage::log('Customer has entered a phone number ');

                //pin code authentification
                $customer2 = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_password', $login['password'])
                    ->getFirstItem();
                Mage::log($customer2); // here i get the right customer

                // Here we will log a customer
                try{
                    if($customer2->getId()){
                        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer2);
                        Mage::log('Customer logged');
                        $this->_redirect('customer/account');
                        return;
                    }else{
                        throw new Exception($this->__('Customer not found'));
                    }
                }catch (Exception $e){
                    $session->addError($e->getMessage());
                }

            //end pin code authentification
            }

            try {
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                switch ($e->getCode()) {
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                        $value = $this->_getHelper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                        $message = $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                        break;
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                        break;
                    default:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
                $session->addError($message);
                $session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
            }
        } else {
            $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
        }
    }

    $this->_loginPostRedirect();
}
```

Comment: I tested it but it's not work, i want to notify you that the code that i have put in the question is in `loginPostAction()` function rewrite. Please look my update @Jaimin Sutariya.

Comment: As per your code, the custom_password will work only if a user has entered a phone number. Please try with phone number and custom password as the code is tested and working

Comment: I have tested it avidently with a phone number, but it doesn't work, in front i have `Error login or password` and in logs i have: `Customer logged` // Mage::log

Comment: Try with updated code

Comment: And if i enter a wrong password i have customer not found in front, i will try your update

Comment: Now i log a customer, but he just check a password without a `login['username']` it's dangerous.

Comment: I have found the issue, i added `->addAttributeToFilter('phone_number', $login['username'])` and now he check the username and password

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You can add filter for combination of mobile number and custom password.

Comment: As I did or you have another one better ?

Comment: You did it the correct way.

Comment: Technically correct answer, but I cannot endorse an answer that encourages storing customer passwords insecurely. This is ecommerce after all and we have a responsibility towards our customers.

Answer (score 2):

> I created two attributes : phone_number and custom_password so when a
>   user enter a phone number he should enter a custom password else when
>   he enter an email adress he enter a natif magento password, and befor
>   saving the custom_password i encrypte it in md5, these attributes i
>   created them like this tuto https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14165/48355

MD5 is **VERY** insecure as a password hashing algorithm, that's not much better than storing them in plain text. Please use [`password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`](http://php.net/password-hash) to store the password instead.

Then, if you detect that the customer entered a phone number instead of an email address, look up the customer by phone number:

```
addAttributeToFilter('phone_number', $login['username'])
```

and use [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/password-verify) to verify the entered password against the stored password hash:

```
if (password_verify($login['password'], $customer->getData('custom_password')) {
    // log in
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, however the `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) ` works fine but `password_verify($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) ` doesn't @Fabian

Comment: because it's wrong :) the hashing algorithm (PASSWORD_BCRYPT) is only determined in `password_hash`, it is then encoded within the hash. the second parameter to `password_verify()` is the password hash from the attribute (read my example again)

Comment: Yes, i understand now and it works:)  i want to know just for information if it's possible to put the password_verify in addAttributeToFilter  `->addAttributeToFilter('custom_password', $login['password'])` and another question: you know in the backoffice I have the password attribute and in its value i have to get the password, so the better is to display it in clear or encrypted, I find it is not very elegant to leave the encrypted one in the backoffice or have you another idea.

Comment: No, you cannot use password_verify in the filter. The stored value is a hash, that's a one way encryption, so you cannot decrypt it. I would use a password input that shows ***** and of  course only save the value if the user entered a new one