# Data upgrade data doesn't work in Magento 1

Tags: database, magento-1, upgrade-script

This is my upgrade script:

```
//mynamespace/mymodule/data/upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php


$eavAttributes = [
    [
        'entity_type_id' => '12',
        'attribute_code' => 'reason_contact',
        'backend_model' => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
        'backend_type' => 'text',
        'frontend_type' => 'multiselect',
        'frontend_label' => 'Reason contact',
        'source_model' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
        'is_required' => '0',
        'is_unique' => '0',
        'is_user_defined' => '1',
        'note' => 'Reason contact for contact profile',
    ],
    [
        'entity_type_id' => '12',
        'attribute_code' => 'result_contact',
        'backend_model' => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
        'backend_type' => 'text',
        'frontend_type' => 'multiselect',
        'frontend_label' => 'Result contact',
        'source_model' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
        'is_required' => '0',
        'is_unique' => '0',
        'is_user_defined' => '1',
        'note' => 'Result contact for contact profile',
    ],
];
// @todo insert more data in other custom tables.
foreach ($eavAttributes as $eavAttribute) {
    Mage::getModel('eav/attribute')
        ->setData($eavAttribute)
        ->save();
}
```

The resources part:

```
    <resources>
        <mynamespace_mymodule_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Mynamespace_Mymodule</module>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </mynamespace_mymodule_setup>
    </resources>
```

I updated my config xml to the 1.0.1 version and it is updated in the core_resources table . But there are no values inserted into `eav_attribute`. Actually I put some exit in my files and it doen't know about this file . What am I missing ? Thnx

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are trying to create new attributes for the customer entity (or maybe I'm wrong ?).

If I'm right, then the way you are trying do doing this is not the standard way.

For more details, you should look [Add a customer attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer) for example.

First, your script must be in a `sql` folder (not `data`).

Then, your `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Setup` should extend `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup`. 
If not you will have to use something like `$setup = Mage::getModel ( 'customer/entity_setup' , 'core_setup' );`.

Then, you script must begin with

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
```

and end with :

```
$installer->endSetup();
```

For further, you should have a look to the methods in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` : `addAttribute`, `updateAttribute`, `removeAttribute`, etc,etc