# How to create a new eav attribute in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, eav, customer-attribute

How can I create a new EAV attribute for customer in Magento 1 using SQL script.

Comment: Please check  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer

Comment: @NikunjVadariya, Thanks, I tried but can't see attribute in backoffice. Can you please help.