# Create custom attribute for customer in Magento 1.9 programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

How can Create custom optional attribute in Magento1.9 for customer  programmatically and how can fetch it.

Comment: What type of attribute do you need (e g text, drop-down)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to follow this link

Link:

https://magentodevsolutions.wordpress.com/2014/06/18/add-customer-attribute-in-admin-programmatically-in-magento/

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14165/77554

This might help you

Comment: it is helpful but it is  not optional attribute